# What the 'set logscale' does in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, natural-logarithm

My question is more about math then the actual code. 
When use the command

```
set logscale
```

on gnuplot 5.0  what is happening ?
It should represents the logarithmic values values of the x and y points.
But it doesn not seems to work properly. For example on my data I have x and y values smaller then 1 so I am expecting to see negative values for these values on the plot, but I see only postivie values.
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Check [Logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) at Wikipedia, especially the **log-log** graph.

Comment: I had already checked on wikipedia before to ask but I don't understand why I don't see negative value for values smaller than one..

Comment: Andrea, put `set format xy "10^{%L}"` to fix the axes labels

Answer (score 2):

A specific example might help to illustrate the effect of logarithmic scaling:

```
set xrange [0.1:10]
plot x**2
```

[image]

Let's plot this again, but this time on a logarithmic scale. Watch how the scaling of the x and y axes changes:

```
set logscale
replot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The logarithmic scale still shows the real values around the axes, just their distances are logarithmic. To really see the negative values, you need to really apply the `log` function:

```
plot "file.dat" using (log($1)):(log($2)) with lines
```

**without** setting the logscale.